# Sum number of days to specific date in dd/mm/yyyy format in bash

Tags: linux, bash

This might be a simple problem but I'm having some trouble getting trough it:

I need to sum a number of weeks to a specific date that is in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

I know I can sum number of weeks to the current day using `date -d "+1 week" +"%d%m%Y"`, but I'm having trouble when I try to do this to a specific date in the format I mentioned above (29/06/2019, for example).

Would anyone be able to explain how I can perform this operation?

Comment: Move to seconds and you are good to go. So: 1. Convert the date to seconds since epoch `date --date=your_date +%s`. 2. Add no_of_weeks * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds to the number. 3. Convert the number of seconds into your great format `date --date=@num_of_seconds +your_format`.

Comment: Please consider providing two files:  Input and expected output (even if you have to calculate it by hand).  Contributors can then more easily see what you are trying to achieve and use your files as test cases.    To be honest, if you had some files I probably would have coded a suggestion for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ date -d '20190629+1 week' +"%d%m%Y"
06072019

$ date -d '06/29/2019+1 week' +"%d%m%Y"
06072019
```

without delimiters it's not a valid date format though.

Comment: To change the OP's date format to the one shown in the first line in this answer, do: `echo $d | sed 's|\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)|\3\2\1|g'` where `d="29/06/2019"`. i.e, this command changes `29/06/2019` to `20190629` Then you can use the first command shown in this answer. @karakfa, could it be the `not a valid date` you are seeing is due to this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127834/invalid-date-error-by-date-command ?